# enable restart stage ability in parallel stage

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

Assume we have this piece of the sample jenkins pipeline..

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo "Building the application"'
                // Add commands to build application
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            parallel {
                stage('Unit Tests') {
                    steps {
                        sh 'sleep 5s'
                        sh 'echo "Running unit tests"'
                        // Add commands to run unit tests
                    }
                }
                stage('Integration Tests') {
                    steps {
                        sh 'echo "Running integration tests"'
                        // Add commands to run integration tests
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo "Deploying the application"'
                // Add commands to deploy application
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when the pipeline is triggered, we will only see

1. build
2. test(unit tests, Integration tests)
3. deploy

Assume due to environment issue, the stage name "unit tests" is failed, directly from build number , we goto "Restart from stage", we will only see build, test, deploy in the drop down box, how do we be able to see "unit tests" and "integration tests" so that we can restart only "unit tests" ?